# Java Simple Bouncing Ball, SingleThread, Mouse Listener, JFrame

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, mouselistener

I've created a Bouncing Ball application in in Java. The goal is to have a ball appear on `mousePressed()` and have it bounce off the walls without leaving the frame. Only one Ball One Thread, should be easy.. **My problem is that every time I click to make the ball appear it gets faster and I have no idea why.** Can somebody help me please. PS: I'm new to threads.

```java
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyFrame extends JPanel {
public int xPos, yPos, xDir = 3, yDir = 4;
public int diameter = 50;

public MyFrame(){
    final JFrame thisFrame = new JFrame();
    thisFrame.add(this);
    thisFrame.setTitle("Bouncing Ball");
    thisFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    thisFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    thisFrame.setSize(500, 500);

    this.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            xPos = e.getX();
            yPos = e.getY();
            Thread t = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while(true){
                        try{
                            Thread.sleep(10);
                        }catch(Exception e){};
                        xPos += xDir;
                        yPos += yDir;

                        if(xPos + diameter >= thisFrame.getWidth() - 25 || xPos <= 0) xDir = -xDir;
                        if(yPos + diameter >= thisFrame.getHeight() - diameter || yPos <= 0) yDir = -yDir;
                        repaint();
                    }
                } 
            };
            t.start();
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
        });

    thisFrame.setVisible(true);

    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
        super.paintComponent(g); 
        g.fillOval(xPos, yPos, diameter, diameter); 
    }
}
```

```java
public class MyMain{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyFrame();
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `MouseAdapter` in the future when you don't need to override every mouse event method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you click, you are starting a new Thread, which means you have another thread updating the x/y positions.

For example, 1 thread means your update the x/p once per sync, 2 means you're updating the x/y position *at least* twice per cycle and this just gets compounded each time you add a new thread.

A better solution would be to start the `Thread` at some time earlier and then use a `List` to maintain the position and direction of the ball.

This will require a little but synchronisation to keep things safe

FYI a delay of 40 milliseconds is roughly 25 fps, 16 milliseconds is roughly 60 fps. IMHO, for what you are doing, 10 milliseconds seems excessive...

Comment: If I understand correctly, every time I click, the previous thread doesn't die. Resulting in multiple threads...? Sorry if I'm a little confused. Are you saying I should have the thread initialized outside the mouse-pressed and start it in the mouse-pressed? If that's the case wouldn't I have to terminate it before starting it again? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes to the first part. The second part will depend on what you want to do. If you only want one ball then, the. You could simply reset the x/y position and not worry about anything else. If you want more balls, then you need to use some kind of list to maintain the information you need to manage each ball

Comment: I should also point out, that a javax.swing.Timer would be easier to manage and safer from an update point of view

Comment: I fixed it man, thanks a lot. I'm gonna test it and post the updated code in a minute. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Well I'll post it tomorrow because I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question. QQ.